# MySQL - select multiple rows from one table into one result row

Tags: mysql

I have a table where are periodically imported values. For statistics use I need to create diff view of two dates.

Table looks like

| name | cpu_count | memory_count | import_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 2 | 4 | 2022-09-28 |
| alpha | 2 | 6 | 2022-10-01 |

and I need select columns like **name, cpu_old, memory_old, cpu_new, memory_new** into one row.

| name | cpu_old | memory_old | cpu_new | memory_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 2 | 4 | 2 | 6 |

Can anybody help me? I was trying it with UNION, GROUP etc but every time I've get two rows.

Comment: is every name has no more than 2 rows?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Import run every week. There will be **where import_date = xx**

Comment: Please update your question, as now it is unclear. Do you have 1 or 2 tables? What is the desired output? What queries have you tried?

Comment: Its solved, first solution from @sukalogika is expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

You have data something like this:

[image: Your data]

**SQL for create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_cpu` (
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `cpu_count` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memory_count` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`import_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii
```

**RESULT:**

[image: Result of QUERY]

**SQL for create that result:**

```
SELECT a.name,
    a.cpu_count AS cpu_old,
    a.memory_count AS memory_old,
    b.cpu_count AS cpu_new  ,
    b.memory_count AS memory_new
FROM `my_cpu`   a INNER JOIN `my_cpu` b ON a.name = b.name
WHERE a.import_date = "2022-09-28" AND b.import_date = "2022-10-01"
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

- Because you store data every week, so you have 2 dates.
- The data is saved in one table_names, lets say it "my_cpu".
- Create self join from my_cpu. So you have 2 table (a and b). With condition a.name = b.name
- Filter where a.import_date = your_old_date and b.import_date =
  your_new_date

**FURTHER READ:**

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp

---

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**

This would be suitable for random/ different import date

Using group_concat and substring_index for different import date.

[image: Data with different date]

**RESULT:**

[image: Result with different date]

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  `name`,

    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cpu_count,",",2),",",-1) cpu_old,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(memory_count,",",2),",",-1) memory_old,
    
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(cpu_count,",",1) cpu_new,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(memory_count,",",1) memory_new
FROM
(

SELECT  `name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`cpu_count` ORDER BY `import_date` DESC) cpu_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`memory_count` ORDER BY `import_date` DESC) memory_count
FROM    `my_cpu`
GROUP
BY NAME
)

AS dbx
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

Create query for get cpu and memory in ordered by import_date in descending each cpu_name

**THE QUERY:**

```
SELECT  `name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`cpu_count` ORDER BY `import_date` DESC) cpu_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`memory_count` ORDER BY `import_date` DESC) memory_count
FROM    `my_cpu`
GROUP
BY NAME
```

**WOULD REPRODUCE:**

[image: Explaination 1]

Search with substring_index,

The lastet would be the first letter before (,)

The second(oldest) would be the the second letter after the (,)

Comment: How will you do if `my_cpu` have 100 rows with different import_date?

Comment: @lucumt OP's question is about the diff between two `import_date`, no more. Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @lucumt I add alternate query with different date. Maybet its would be a solution